# Script gives error like _content.DestroyChildren()

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I make this room listing and I don't understand what I should do with this error . I have a  other scripts but I don't know if I should do one for DestroyChildren or something. I should delete the DestroyChildren? or I should change it with something? Or add something to it to work? I also get this error with created room when I start the game , what I should add in the inspector?
[image]

```css
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RoomListingsMenu : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform _content;
    [SerializeField]
    private RoomListing _roomListing;

    private List<RoomListing> _listings = new List<RoomListing>();
    private RoomsCanvases _roomsCanvases;


    public void FirstInitialize(RoomsCanvases canvases)
    {
        _roomsCanvases = canvases;
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        _roomsCanvases.CurrentRoomCanvas.Show();
        _content.DestroyChildren();
        _listings.Clear();
    }

    public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
    {
        foreach (RoomInfo info in roomList)
        {
            //Removed from rooms list.
            if (info.RemovedFromList)
            {
                int index = _listings.FindIndex(x => x.RoomInfo.Name == info.Name);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    Destroy(_listings[index].gameObject);
                    _listings.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            }
            //Added to rooms list.
            else
            {
                int index = _listings.FindIndex(x => x.RoomInfo.Name == info.Name);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    RoomListing listing = Instantiate(_roomListing, _content);
                    if (listing != null)
                    {
                        listing.SetRoomInfo(info);
                        _listings.Add(listing);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Modify listing here.
                    //_listings[index].dowhatever.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are missing some 'using' or some implementation of this extension method.

I will assume that this one is from https://github.com/Mckenon/Unity-Utils/blob/master/Utils/Transform.cs

You can use this whole library, or a single class `Transform.cs` or write your own extension class and method if you like:

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class TransformExtensions
{
    public static void DestroyChildren(this Transform t)
    {
        for (int i = t.childCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            MonoBehaviour.Destroy(t.GetChild(i));
    }
}
```